# SQL queries, comparing data between tables, strings and ints

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

This is more of an "approach" question, I haven't gotten to the code yet. But am new to SQL and php and would like to tackle this issue intelligently.

The scenario is as follows:

I have a table called Donations, each of which has exactly one string value in the column called AREA. AREA may have any one of nine predetermined values (Northeast, Northwest, Downtown, etc...).

I also have a table of Volunteers, each of which has specified which regions they are willing to travel to, to help pick-up the donations. For each volunteer, I have 9 columns, each with a 1 or 0, corresponding to the nine areas listed above (NW, NE, DT, etc...)

I would like to run a query, series of queries or php/sql combination where by I can search for all active donations, attain which AREA's they are in, then query the Volunteers table, and get back a list of email address for only those Volunteers willing to travel to one or more of those areas.

Any help is appreciated. (As an aside, there is no key value shared between these two tables.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this via a totally different method altogether, though I am sure the above methods would have worked.

I created assigned each area a prime number, beginning with 2, 3, 5, etc...Then when a Volunteer registered, it creates a code for them by multiplying those areas they are willing to go to.

I used the same primes for donations and assigned each donation the appropriate prime.

Then I ran this join query, seeing if the Volunteer's code was evenly divisble by any of the available donations.

$q = "Select Distinct(EMAIL) from PUPS where EXISTS (Select * from Donations where STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND (REGIONCODE Mod AREAPRIME  = 0))";

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making Areas its own table (ID, Name).  Then for the Donations table you add AreaID (ForeignKey) instead of the Area string column.

For the Volunteers - Areas association I would consider making a linking table named VolunteerAreas which has a structure of VolunteerID, AreaID.

It should be simple to write some scripts to take existing data and dump it into the new format.

Then you could do...

Get active donations

```
SELECT * FROM Donations WHERE Active = 1
```

Get emails from selected area

```
SELECT Email FROM Volunteers v
JOIN VolunteerAreas va ON va.VolunteerID = v.ID
WHERE va.AreaID = @AreaID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is gonna look something like

```
SELECT [area] FROM [database] WHERE donationSelector = selectedValue
```

Then set a variable `$i` to the column name based on the `$area` variable you got from above

```
<?php
switch($area) {
    case "Northwest" :
        $i = "NW";
        break;
    case "Northeast" :
        $i = "NE";
        break;
    ...etc.
}
```

then do another query

```
SELECT * FROM [database] WHERE %s = 1, $i
```

Comment: Hey Hans, the above lokos good, but wouldn't it only work for one Donation? I need it to be able to return several Donations at once.

Comment: in that case, just put that code in a `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` block, then `$area = $row['AREA'];`. Then $i is now a string you're building, with a `$i .= ((strlen($i) > 0) ? "WHERE NE = 1" : " AND NE = 1");`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend a change to your schema, using multiple tables instead of two.

*The SQL below is a skeleton without primary keys, foreign keys, indexes, etc.*

```
CREATE TABLE area (
  id           INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
  name         VARCHAR(128)
)

CREATE TABLE volunteer (
  id           INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
  name         VARCHAR(128)
)

CREATE TABLE coverage (
  area_id      INT,
  volunteer_id INT
)
```

First, using the surrogate primary key (the id column) in each of the first two tables, means that you can change the names of entities without breaking anything.

Second, as you add new areas, you only need to add new records to each table, not new binary flag fields to the volunteers table.

Third, the queries become a lot neater, more maintainable, and faster...

```
SELECT
  volunteer.*
FROM
  area
INNER JOIN
  coverage
    ON area.id = coverage.area_id
INNER JOIN
  volunteer
    ON volunteer.id = coverage.volunteer_id
WHERE
  area.name IN ('NW', 'SE')
GROUP BY
  volunteer.id
```